# Using a variable retrieved with $.post outside this $.post function

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to load a set of data from a mysql database and use it in a calendar function written in jquery, but I'm having trouble using the retrieved data outside the $.post function.
Right now, I've hardcoded the data in the function and this works fine, looks (simplified, I off course need more than just alerting the data) like this:

```
onRender: function(date) {      
    var redArray = ['2011815','2011820','2011824','2011825'];       
    alert(redArray);
}
```

Now I'd like to retrieve those numbers from my database with something like:

```
onRender: function(date) {      
    $.post("../actions/calendar.php", {datetype: "1"}, function(data){
        if(data.length >0) {
            redArray = data;
        }
    },"json");  
    alert(redArray);
}
```

But the alert gives nothing, or undefined. How can I use what I got from my php-file, outside of this $.post-thing? I need the variable later on, I cannot stay in the $.post function!

Comment: possible duplicate of [In jQuery.post, how do I get value of variable outside function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904376/in-jquery-post-how-do-i-get-value-of-variable-outside-function)

Comment: It's because of how Ajax works (asynchronous).

Comment: I know I can get to alert the value WITHIN $.post, but that's not what I need! I need it OUTSIDE the post, I really do.
How do I load something and still use it afterwards?

Comment: You have no way of knowing when redArray will be filled (it could take several seconds). So if you have code that relies on that data, you should execute that code in response to the POST returning (i.e. the callback). The other way is to poll (using something like setTimeout) but this is usually a sign of inappropriate design. I appreciate that you want the variable in another part of the code but you need to make sure that code doesn't execute until you have filled the variable. This is really a design issue more than anything.

Answer (score 0):

$.post is asynchronous

```
onRender: function(date) {      
    $.post("../actions/calendar.php", {datetype: "1"}, function(data){
        if(data.length >0) {
            redArrayReady(data);
        }
    },"json");  
}

function redArrayIsReady(redArray) {
    // work with array
    redArray.length > 0 === true; // true
}
```

so you need to wait for data to be returned from your server.

Comment: Don't forget to declare `redArray` if it's not declared before - nobody likes implied globals.

Comment: But I need it outside of the $.post-function. How do I do that?

Comment: @user: You can't. All the code that needs to work with the result has to be inside or called from the callback function.

Comment: I've updated using a function to call if redArray has elements

Comment: I'm not sure I get this new solution. Can you explain some more?

Comment: You got an answer that you understand, now you should mark that as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Ajax callback (POST) is asynchronous. The POST is fired to the server and your code continues immediately to the next line (the alert). So it's getting there before the response comes back from the server.

The way to solve this is to put your handling of the response inside the callback. e.g.

```
onRender: function(date) {      
    $.post("../actions/calendar.php", {datetype: "1"}, function(data){
        if(data.length >0) {
            redArray = data;
            alert(redArray);
        }
    },"json");  

}
```