# Global variable is not visible inside the anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax call like this:

```
var test = []
$.ajax( {
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    success : function(xhr, textStatus, xmlReq) {
        callbackFnc = function() { callBack(attributesToSearch, searchText,checkForApproval); };
        fetch(xhr, textStatus, xmlReq, attributesToSearch, searchText, callbackFnc);
    }
});
```

And I have an variable called `test`, this is a global variable. But this variable isn't visible, inside the `callBack` function. I'm getting `undefined` if I try to use them:

```
function callBack(//args)
  console.log(test) //undefined
}
```

Where I'm making mistake?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904376/in-jquery-post-how-do-i-get-value-of-variable-outside-function

Comment: Is `test` really a global variable? Or is the top code inside a function?

Comment: Maybe the code at top is inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` and the `callBack` function isn't?

Comment: test is defined in another file. actually.

Comment: because if `test` is really a global variable, it should be accessible anywhere.

Comment: If you want to make sure test is global, there are two ways to do it, though it is really a bad idea to do it: 1. declare test = [] without the var. 2. declare it on the window object like this: window.test = []. Both options are a bad idea and you should really find another way.

Comment: @Barmar: …except it's shadowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few reason that were covered in the comments that might cause this. a simple solution would be to define and call it in the window scope:

```
window.test = []
```

and later

```
console.log(window.test);
```